# Paragraph text got appended while giving backspace

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, firefox, ckeditor

When I press the Backspace Key at the starting point of Paragraph text that para got appended with it's Previous Paragraph text in CKEditor.

I have tried this in
-- CKEDITOR 4.0 and latest version
-- FireFox 34
-- Chrome 38

see the below image

[image]
[image]

eg:

abc

def

Both are Separate Paragraph

Its got appened has

abcdef

Single Paragraph

Please help me to overcome from this Problem

Comment: Does this have anything particular to do with programming..?

Comment: it just formatting style of editor in order to see effect firstly select two paragraph and then click on source tab than again click on paragraph format if you will change paragraph format and then look on source code u will notice your content will be wrapped in differnt html tags say h1 h3 pre ,p

Answer (score 0):

Well... I guess that you want to change the default behaviour, what simply requires implementing the new behaviour.

Use the [`editor#key`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-key) event (with a high priority to execute it before the default handlers) and implement the expected one. The rest will be pretty straightforward - [get selection](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getSelection), [play](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.walker) with the [DOM](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element) and [ranges](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range), calculate final position of the caret and [place it](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.selection-method-selectRanges). Depending on what you want to achieve (because you haven't explained that) you'll need 100-1000LOC and similar amount of tests.